# How do i set dynamic default value of a rest data source in oracle apex?

Tags: api, rest, oracle-apex

I have just started learning oracle apex.
I imported an external API into oracle apex(`https://localhost/report/?dateFrom=2022-09-30&dateTo=2022-10-01`) . This API has two parameters **dateFrom** and **dateTo**. I want to dynamically set the datefrom parameter to 5 days ago and dateTo to today in default value. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define the parameter value *for the component*, which is using the REST data source. If that is, for instance, a report, you can configure within the **Parameters** Node in Page Designer. In the tree on the left hand side, click the node for your parameter, and then (in the **Attributes** pane on the right, choose **Expression** or **Function Body**, and enter the expression to compu For a REST Synchronization (download data to local table), you would configure the same as a **Synchronization Step**.

These options will configure the dynamic value at the component level (the component which uses the REST Data Source).

However, your question reads like you're after a default to be applied to *all* components using that REST Data Source. The Expression or Function Body options are not available at the REST Source level. I'd see two approaches:

- Define an application item (APP_REST_DATEFROM), and a Application Computation to set the value for this item. In the REST Source, then simply use &APP_REST_DATEFROM. as the value for your parameter. At the component level, it's important to switch the parameter value to **REST Source Default**.
- Another option allows you to completely take these parameters out of the REST Source configuration, but implies some PL/SQL coding effort: You could author a *REST Source Plug-In*, where the Plug-In code implements custom handling for all aspects of the HTTP requests being made for the REST Data Source. That typically includes pagination, but can include all parameter handling (HTTP Header, URL Parameters, etc). An example for such a Plug-In is here: https://github.com/oracle/apex/tree/22.1/plugins/rest-source/fixed-page-size

I hope this helps.